# Symfony form not set entity relation

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have entity OutboundInvoice for OneToMany to entity OutboundInvoiceRow
And I create form with CollectionType for OutboundInvoice and when I add some OutboundInvoiceRow in my DB not see `invoice_id` in  OutboundInvoiceRow but when `$form->handleRequest($request);` in debug I see OutboundInvoice with collection OutboundInvoiceRow and in inside see my OutboundInvoiceRow. I try debug and not entry in entity OutboundInvoice in function addRows or addRow. Now I have entity OutboundInvoice with collection OutboundInvoiceRow but after flush in DB OutboundInvoiceRow without OutboundInvoice. Where set OutboundInvoice to OutboundInvoiceRow or how correct using form ???

```
class OutboundInvoice
{
//
    /**
 * @var \OutboundInvoiceRow
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OutboundInvoiceRow", mappedBy="invoice", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $rows;
//
    /**
 * Add row
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoiceRow $row
 *
 * @return OutboundInvoice
 */
public function addRow(\AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoiceRow $row)
{
    $this->rows[] = $row;

    $row->setInvoice($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param OutboundInvoiceRow[] $rows
 * @return $this
 */
public function addRows($rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row instanceof OutboundInvoiceRow) {
            $this->addRow($row);   
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

my entity OutboundInvoiceRow

```
class OutboundInvoiceRow
{
    /**
 * @var \OutboundInvoice
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OutboundInvoice", inversedBy="rows", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 */
private $invoice;
//
    /**
 * Set invoice
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoice $invoice
 *
 * @return OutboundInvoiceRow
 */
public function setInvoice(\AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoice $invoice = null)
{
    $this->invoice = $invoice;

    return $this;
}
```

my action

```
    public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new OutboundInvoice();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('new_outbound_invoices'));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

    private function createCreateForm(OutboundInvoice $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new OutboundInvoiceForm(), $entity, array(
        'validation_groups' => ['post_out_bound_invoice'],
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('outbound_invoices_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
```

my form

```
class OutboundInvoiceForm extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
////
        ->add('rows', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => OutBoundInvoiceRowType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'prototype_name' => 'rows__name__',
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => OutboundInvoice::class,
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
}
```

this my entity when debug after submit and valid form

```
$entity = {AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoice} [27]
id = null
invoiceNumber = null
receiver = null
streetAddress = null
postal = null
postOffice = null
invoicingEmail = null
edi = null
dueDate = null
reversedVat = true
invoiceDate = null
referenceNumber = null
customerReference = "qqqq"
companyReference = "qqqq"
message = "ddd"
notes = "dddd"
termsOfPayment = 22
status = "draft"
currencyCode = "EUR"
languageCode = "FI"
netvisorId = null
crmCustomer = null
customer = {AppBundle\Entity\Customer} [17]
inboundInvoice = null
invoicingType = null
serviceCompany = null
rows = {Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection} [1]
 elements = {array} [1]
  rows0 = {AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoiceRow} [13]
   id = null
   description = "qqq"
   unitPrice = "22"
   amount = "22"
   vat = 3
   unit = "22"
   accountingAccount = null
   contract = null
   crmContract = null
   costObject = null
   taskExecution = null
   invoice = null //why not out bound invoice id ?? after flush still empty 
   location = {AppBundle\Entity\Location} [38]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'type' => new OutBoundInvoiceRowType()` is wrong, you should use [entry_type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-type) option instead

You don't have `removeRow` method in your entity

Doctrine will check only owning side for cascade operations so you don't have to declare cascade operations in your `OutboundInvoiceRow` entity

And add `'by_reference' => false` to your form (among collection options).

Comment: I try ` 'entry_type' => OutBoundInvoiceRowType::class,` but still no set invoice to row. I have `removeRow` update my question, but what it affects when we create entity. And I have `cascade={"persist"}` in entities

Comment: Oh yes and add 'by_reference' => false to your form. It'll call addRow method explicitly.

And I meant you don't need keep `cascade` settings in your `OutboundInvoiceRow` entity. Just take a look to http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

And probably you need to initialize $rows as empty ArrayCollection() object in your `OutboudInvoice` entity. Just set it in the constructor. And use `$rows->add()` instead of `$rows[]`

Comment: add `'by_reference' => false` in what form ? OutboundInvoiceForm or in OutBoundInvoiceRowType or to `->add('rows', CollectionType::class`. And when I add ``'by_reference' => false`` and when when `handleRequest` code enter in addRow function in `OutboudInvoice` entity?

Comment: `OutboundInvoiceForm` (the same array where you specified `allow_add`, `allow_delete` etc.). `by_reference => false` means that methods that populate entity will be called explicitly. Otherwise, values will be set via Reflection.